# How do I print the software title and installed date from system_profiler in macOS?

Tags: macos, awk, sed, grep

I'm setting up a txt/log file that will store information from `system_profiler SPInstallHistoryDataType` that matches "Security Update" and "macOS 10.x.x Update" and the installation dates so I can then push this information to our MDM solution.

When I run 
`system_profiler SPInstallHistoryDataType | grep "Security"`
I only get the output of

```
Security Update 2017-001:
Security Update 2018-001:
Security Update 2018-001:
```

When running just `system_profiler SPInstallHistoryDataType`, you'll get an output that looks like

[Output of system_profiler SPInstallHistoryDataType](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwPHY.png)

```
    macOS 10.14.3 Update

        Source: Apple
        Install Date: 2/3/19, 3:11 PM

    GarageBand

        Version: 10.1.3
        Source: Apple
        Install Date: 1/31/19, 4:48 PM

    Google Drive File Stream:

       Source: 3rd Party
       Install Date: 3/3/19, 11:30 AM
```

I'm trying to get something like

```
Security Update 2017-001,2018-02-31 18:11
macOS 10.14.3 Update,2019-02-03 15:11
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Show output from `system_profiler SPInstallHistoryDataType` that includes what you are trying to extract from it.

Comment: I've included a screenshot of the output -- the list is too long to fit in terminal window

Comment: You might be better off running `system_profiler -xml SPInstallHistoryDataType` and then using perl, python, or ruby to parse the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can probably be optimized quite a bit, but you can use:

```
system_profiler SPInstallHistoryDataType | grep -A 4 "macOS\|Security" | grep "macOS\|Security\|Install Date" | tr '\n' ' ' | sed -e 's/[AP]M/&\
/g' | sed -e 's/Install Date://g' | tr -s ' '
```

To spell that out a bit, you grep for both 'macOS' and 'Security', and allow the following 4 lines to return.

Then you pipe that through a grep for 'macOS', 'Security', and 'Install Date', so you only get the first line and the line with the date.

Then you pipe it through tr (translate) and turn all newlines into spaces.

Then you look for AM and PM, and add a newline after (in this case, I couldn't seem to use sed's 'a' [append] command, so there is an actual newline in the middle of this command)

Then you pipe it through sed again to remove "Install Date:"

And finally, you pipe it through tr again to turn multiple spaces into a single space to make it more readable.

The output then looks like this:

```
 macOS High Sierra 10.13.4 Update: 4/6/18, 12:03 PM
 Security Update 2018-001: 5/11/18, 2:59 PM
 Security Update 2018-001: 5/11/18, 3:04 PM
 macOS High Sierra 10.13.5 Update: 6/20/18, 10:32 AM
```

You would have to do more work if you want your date format changed.  But at least this might help get you started.

Answer (score 0):

How many addition line or info from Security Update if it's, e.g. 3 and/or less, put -C3 option

```
$ system_profiler SPInstallHistoryDataType | grep -EC3 "^\s*(Security|macOS)\b"
macOS 10.14.3 Update

        Source: Apple
        Install Date: 2/3/19, 3:11 PM
```